# How to add an argument/parameter to the safety closure in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

CoffeeScript adds `(function() { ... }).call(this);` to compiled files.  Is there a way to add a dependency, like jQuery for example.  Then the closer would look like this:

```
(function(jQuery) {
    ...
}).call(this, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't edit the safety wrapper, and also probably shouldn't. If you want to close over jQuery as you put above, I recommend just doing so in coffee-script, without worrying about the safety wrapper:

```
(($) ->

).call(this, jQuery)
```

renders as:

```
(function(){
   (function($) {

   }).call(this, jQuery);
}).call(this);
```

its going to give you the same functionality.

---

Or alternatively, you could just use the `do` keyword:

```
do (jQuery) ->
```

renders as:

```
(function(jQuery) {

})(jQuery);
```

instant closure!

Comment: Why shouldn't you change the safety wrapper?